# PHP Fractions are correct but the wrong way round

Tags: php, math

Using PHP for a couple of mathematical operations, mainly reducing price by an arbitrary fraction amount.

Like this:

```
(75 / 100) * 80;
```

This outputs $60, but for the purposes of a web shopping cart, a 75% reduction should equal $20. Is there something I am missing or some way to "inverse" the result?

Comment: For the inverse, just subtract from the start value (80)?

Comment: Isn't it a task for primary school?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do something like `(1- (75/100)) * 80;` which will evaluate to `20`.